# How to get "alpha" layer data from ".dds" image based on x and y using pyglet?

Tags: python, image, transparency, pyglet, dds-format

#### Given:

There is `white_small.png`, contains RGBA.
And there is `white_small.dds` which was generated from previous one.
JFYI: it was generated by this way, using [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.5/)

```
from wand import image
with image.Image(filename="white_small.png") as img:
    img.flip()  # it just requred for more convenient using in pyglet scripts
    # flip is not important for further case
    img.compression = "dxt3"
    img.save(filename="white_small.dds")
```

So, for an example if I want to know "Is pixel under x=2 and y=3 transparent in `white_small.png`"  it could be easily done.

```
import pyglet
img_png = pyglet.image.load("white_small.png")  # 16*16
png_transparency_data = [
    img_png.data[3::4][line * 16: (line + 1) * 16 - 1]  # take every 4-th byte from RGBA
    for line in range(16)
]
# png_transparency_data is
# [b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
#  b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff']
```

It's quite clear: `png_transparency_data[(y-1)][(x-1)]` which is 0 - means it's transparent.

Now about `white_small.dds`. If `white_small.dds` will be open in GIMP/any_editor - following picture will be shown: ( just user imagination to see this bytes in 
 white color :) )

```
[b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff',
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

Let's look into `white_small.dds` using pyglet:

```
import pyglet
img = pyglet.image.load("white_small.dds")  # 16*16
dds_all_data = [img.data[line * 16: (line + 1) * 16 - 1] for line in range(16)]
# dds_all_data is
[b'\x00\x05\xff\x8f\xff\xc0\x0f\xe0\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x01\x05',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\x8f\xff\xc0\x0f\xe0\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x01\x05',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\x8f\xff\xc0\x0f\xe0\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x01\x05',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'\x00\x05\xff\x8f\xff\xc0\x0f\xe0\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x01\x05']
```

And here I have no idea how to map this data to coordinates.

#### Question:

How to get information(transparency/color) about x and y coordinate from `.dds` data?

PS: I know, that `dxt3` compress image in ration 4:1, but it doesn't give me a clue for solving my question :(

Comment: found documentation https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_compression_s3tc.txt And following text `alpha(x,y) = bits[4*(4*y+x)+3 .. 4*(4*y+x)+0]` trying to apply it on my data.